Which side of a relationship can have entities that may not be associated with any entity on the other side: the "one" side or the "many" side?
Which side of relationship(In all possible mapping cardinality) can have entities that are not associated with any entity on the other side: the "one" side or the "many" side or "both"?
Which side can have entity with no association? Both?

someone made a joke or there is a problem in the translation: an entity that is no associated with any other entity has no relationships. If it has a relationship it must be associated somehow to the other side. There can be no other side (if relationships a represented with diamonds) in the case of relfexive relationship. Depending on the exact wording you can have entities that are associated withe the other side but where it is possible that an instance has no couterpart on the other side if the participation is partial, e.g cardinality 0..1 or 0..N.

You may want to check the [tour] and [ask]
